# Can sealed self leveling underlayment alone support the weight of a washer and dryer on a laundry room floor?

Tags: basement, washing-machine, self-leveling-concrete, laundry

In my laundry room, I poured some [LevelQuik RS self leveling underlayment](https://www.custombuildingproducts.com/products/levelquik-rs-rapid-setting-self-leveling-underlayment) over a lumpy concrete slab (I put cement primer on first). The underlayment was about 1/4 inch thick at the thinnest parts. I was planning to seal it with [a 2 part epoxy sealer](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/epoxyshield/garage-concrete-floor-coatings/garage-floor-coating) and use that as the floor surface. I want something durable, low maintenance, relatively easy to install from this point forward, and easy to keep clean.

Is it okay to use self leveling underlayment + epoxy sealer as a floor surface with a washer and dryer on it? I am mainly concerned about it cracking under the weight of the washer and dryer. I spoke with customer service at the manufacturer of LevelQuik, and they said they can't guarantee this application since tile or engineered wood would help distribute the weight, but they also said customers have done it and they haven't heard back from them, so maybe it worked out for them.

I searched about acceptable applications of self leveling concrete, and found [this](https://duomit.com/can-self-leveling-concrete-be-used-as-a-finished-floor/) and [this](https://blog.portamix.com/can-self-levelling-concrete-coating-be-used-as-a-finished-floor), which say something like:

> Self-leveling concrete can be used as a finished floor in most interior spaces. It's strong and durable, standing up to foot traffic and everyday wear and tear.

and not to use it outdoors or on vertical surfaces

But they don't say anything about weight concerns with a washer and dryer.

Comment: Generally, all the weight is on 4 small points (the feet) which could penetrate through a thin spot in the self-lever. Have you considered setting the washer/dryer on a piece of plywood to spread the weight?

Comment: @FreeMan clever solution as far as weight, but I anticipate plywood under the washer would cause other problems - like it would probably occasionally get wet and then moldy

Comment: Many people put a "spill pan" under the washer these days in case of overflow. Put that between the washer & plywood?

Comment: Good idea. Would a plastic spill pan itself sufficiently distribute the load across a wide enough area to minimize the risk of cracking the cement?

Comment: Plastic or metal - depends on how thick it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their technical literature:

> Do not use as a permanent wear surface.

It also mentions:

> Prime all surfaces with an appropriate Custom® primer before application of LevelQuik RS. Refer to LevelQuik® Advanced Acrylic Primer for porous surfaces, MBP Multi Surface Bonding Primer or TechPrime™ E 100%-Solids Epoxy Primer technical datasheets.

Custom is the company that produces Redgard, so that plus its invocation of ASTM C627 ("Standard Test Method for Evaluating Ceramic Floor Tile Installation Systems Using the Robinson-Type Floor Tester") suggest to me that this product is intended for use beneath ceramic tile. It mentions many other use cases below a wearing surface, but it's intended as a tile substrate.

At this point I would just go for it and call it an experiment.

Comment: Yes, I realize that's the intended use. I'm wondering practically if I can get away with using the sealed underlayment as a floor surface and support a washer and dryer with it. 

Yes, I could experiment, but it would be a somewhat labor-intensive experiment if it goes wrong. Someone must have tried this already…

Comment: @Mike Eng, I would worry mostly about impact resistance. They mention a minimum concrete tensile strength at the surface of 200 psi. Whack the surface with a hammer, and I can imagine the shock causing enough tension to debond a chunk of the stuff. With compressive strength of 4300 psi, the stuff is stronger against crushing than most slabs. The nice flat bearing surfaces of appliances and light vibration wouldn't worry me.

Answer (score 1):

USG and Mapei have self levelers that can be used as a finished floor. Maybe you can add a thin coating of 1/8" which is the minimum.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! If you'll take the [tour] and have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), you'll see were looking for something a little stronger than a "maybe you can..." answer.